# Meeting point in a circular race

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> X and Y walk around a circular course 100 km from the same point. If
>   they walk at 5 kmph and 7 kmph respectively in the same direction when
>   will they meet?

Answer according to [sscexamguide.com](http://www.sscexamguide.com/2015/09/quantitative-aptitude-practice-questions-for-SSC-CGL-mains-fci-exams-set-23.html) (5th question) is 140 hours

Answer according to [careerbless.com](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=1208) is 50 hours

Both uses entirely different approaches for this problem.

What I have done

> If the answer is 140 hours, X would have travelled 5*140=700 km and Y
>   would have travelled in 7*140=980 km, in 140 hours. So, these will be
>   two points and cannot be a point where both meet
>
> If the answer is 50 hours, X would have travelled 5*50 =250 km and Y
>   would have travelled in 7*50=350 km, in 50 hours. Since the
>   circumference is 100 km, they will be at the same point. So, 50 may be
>   the right answer, but not sure.
>
> Can somebody confirm this whether the right approach for this problem is to divide circumference by relative speed (here, 100/2=50 hr) as the latter site did? I got this doubt as the former site uses LCM that I am not able to understand.

Comment: Yes. The smallest solution is $t$ hours where $7t=5t+100$, so $t=50$.

Comment: Yes, 50 hours is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance (along the course) between the walkers change by $7-5=2$ kilometers every hour.

This means that if they keep walking forever, the faster walker will overtake the slower every $50$ hours.

The problem doesn't state really clearly how far from each other the walkers *start*, but this should make it clear that the answer cannot possibly be *more than* $50$ hours.

The answer method at sscexamguide.com doesn't not make any sense to me. It is true that the least common multiple of 7, 5, and 100 is 700, but why the author thought this least common multiple would be relevant is a mystery. Perhaps the writer tried to look for an event where the walkers meet *on the start/finish line* and *right at the stroke of an hour* -- but even with that assumption the computation least common multiple is not the right thing to compute: a meeting on the start line will happen after exactly 100 hours (with the walkers having made 5 and 7 full circuits, respectively).